# How to count number of pairs of subsets $(A,B)$ of $ X=\{1,2,..,100\}$ under the given constraint?

Tags: combinatorics

For a pair $(A,B)$ of subsets of the set $X=\{1,2,3,...,100\}$, let $A\Delta B$ denote the set of all elements of $X$ which belong to exactly one of $A$ or $B.$ What is the number of pairs $(A,B)$ of subsets of $X$ such that $A\Delta
B=\{2,4,...,100\}?$

Comment: The operation "*" is known as the symmetric difference, and usually denoted by $\triangle$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: What can you say about each element in $A\triangle B$? What can you say about each element not in $A\triangle B$?

Comment: Yes, it's just a difference in notation, but how to count? I never came across this sort of operation earlier.

Comment: There is no involved counting necessary here. The essential point is to  s e e  what kind of pairs $A$, $B$ are possible under the given constraint.

Comment: I think we're being too subtle. Five hours, and no one (but me) has upvoted your answer, and no one at all has upvoted mine.

Comment: @Bhaskar:  to follow up on Yuval and Gerry-If $1 \in A$, is $1 \in B$?  If $2 \in A$, is $2 \in B$?

Comment: @Gerry *Five hours* does not seem much. And I like waaaay more your hints and Yuval's and Ross's than the flat answers given to obvious homework questions too often on this site.

Answer (score 4):

Different hint: given $A$, how many different possibilities are there for $B$?

Comment: I like your hint better.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another hint: show that the set of all subsets of $X$ forms a group under symmetric difference, then note that you're asking how many times a given group element shows up in the group table.